# How to get list of custom user types for listed stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to find way to find custom user types for one stored procedure:

```sql
select referenced_entity_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('#procedure name here#', 'OBJECT')
where referenced_class_desc = 'TYPE'
```

How should I use this function for comma separated list of stored procedures?

Comment: do you mean you want to apply the above for a specific list of procedure names?

Comment: for me select * from STRING_SPLIT('#procedure names#', ',') will work fine, I am confused a bit with usage of this list with function that returns another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it available (SQL Server 2016 and newer), you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split your list and then use `CROSS APPLY` to call the function for each of the items in the list.

```
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(1000) = 'p_Proc1,p_Proc2';

SELECT referenced_entity_name
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@list, ',') ss
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(ss.value, 'OBJECT')
where referenced_class_desc = 'TYPE';
```